# Map subdomain and sub-subdomains to different IP

Tags: domain-name-system, subdomain

I have two servers, let's assume their IPs are `1.1.1.1` and `2.2.2.2`.

I also have a domain, let's call that `foo.com`.

Currently, I have the following DNS records:

```
A:     foo.com   -> 1.1.1.1
A:     x.foo.com -> 2.2.2.2
CNAME: *.foo.com -> foo.com
```

`x.foo.com` correctly resolves to `2.2.2.2`, but `test.x.foo.com` resolves to `1.1.1.1`, which is not what I want.

My aim is to have `x.foo.com` and all sub-subdomains (`*.x.foo.com`) resolve to `2.2.2.2`.

I suspect I need to add a record like this: `CNAME: *.x.foo.com -> x.foo.com` but my domain registrar's website doesn't let me do that.

Is this a limitation of my domain registrar or am I missing something else I can do to make this work like I want it to?